# Dynamically change Material Button background not working

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a Material button, i want to change its background dynamically, i have created drawable xml for that, previously it was working, now its not working, i tried below options, still my button is blue color only

```
mBtnStudy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.switch_left_enabled);
mBtnStudy.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
mBtnStudy.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.switch_left_enabled));
mBtnStudy.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.switch_left_enabled));
```

and xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="16dp">
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_study"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="@string/study"/>

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_test_yourself"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="@string/test_yourself"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--<corners android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp" android:topLeftRadius="10dp"/>-->
    <solid android:color="#bdbdbd"/>
</shape>
```

What might be the issue?

Comment: add this to your view  app:backgroundTint="@null"

Answer (score 0):

In java file `button.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);`
Replace RED to Your Desired Color.
And to use Color Code Use `button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#03dac5");`

Comment: Its not working, i already tried this, i mentioned in the question, i don't know what i am missing, after long time i am working on android, i was working on flutter these days

Comment: try adding android:clickable=true to the buttons @sagar